# Using MVVM to bind MarkerFill and Title of telerik:LegendItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I use telerik to create a chart. Now I am going to add legend to it.
The example is at [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radlegend/itemtemplate).

The xaml is:

```
<telerik:RadLegend HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True">
<telerik:RadLegend.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Background="{Binding MarkerFill}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{Binding MarkerStroke}">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" Margin="15 0 0 0" />
                <Path Width="12" 
                      Height="12" 
                      Fill="White" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <Binding Path="ActualMarkerGeometry"
                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:LegendItemControl}">
                        </Binding>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:RadLegend.ItemTemplate>
<telerik:RadLegend.Items>
    <telerik:LegendItemCollection>
        <telerik:LegendItem MarkerFill="#FF55AA33" MarkerStroke="Black" Title="Legend item 1" />
        <telerik:LegendItem MarkerFill="#FFCC3399" MarkerStroke="Black" Title="Legend item 2" />
        <telerik:LegendItem MarkerFill="#FF5511BB" MarkerStroke="Black" Title="Legend item 3" />
    </telerik:LegendItemCollection>
</telerik:RadLegend.Items>
```

However it is hard coded. I want to bind it with MVVM. Not sue how to bind `MarkerFill` and `MarkerStroke`. I don't think that it is a string property.

What type of it in the ViewModel?

EDIT:

```
 ObservableCollection<ChartData> data = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>();
        data.Add(new ChartData() { Category = "Red", Title = "one" });
        data.Add(new ChartData() { Category = "Green", Title = "two" });
        data.Add(new ChartData() { Category = "Blue", Title = "three" });
        data.Add(new ChartData() { Category = "Aqua", Title = "four" });
```

Comment: MarkerFill and MarkerStroke are Brush properties. Are you trying to be able to change the values dynamically at runtime? Or just avoid hardcoding hex values in your markup?

Comment: The colors are from viewmodel. I want to bind them instread of hardcording hex values. See the EDIT.

Comment: LegendItem is not a DependencyObject, so you cannot bind to its properties. Since you are already defining an ItemTemplate, have you tried binding the colors in the template itself? You could have the colors defined in your viewmodel and use a custom converter to convert from color to Brush.

Comment: I thought about it. Just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the Telerik libraries to verify, but can you try something like this?:

**View**

```
<telerik:RadLegend HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" Items={Binding LegendItems}>
    <telerik:RadLegend.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="{Binding Category, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" Margin="15 0 0 0" />
                    <Path Width="12" 
                          Height="12" 
                          Fill="White" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Data="{Binding Data}" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadLegend.ItemTemplate>
</telerik.RadLegend>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase // Or whatever your base is
{
    public ObservableCollection<ChartData> LegendItems 
    {
        get;
    } = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        data.Add(new ChartData() { Title="Legend Item 1", Category = "Red", Title = "one", Data=".." });
        data.Add(new ChartData() { Title="Legend Item 2", Category = "Green", Title = "two", Data=".." });
        data.Add(new ChartData() { Title="Legend Item 3", Category = "Blue", Title = "three", Data=".." });
        data.Add(new ChartData() { Title="Legend Item 4", Category = "Aqua", Title = "four", Data=".." });
    }
}
```

**Converter**

```
public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(value?.ToString()) as Brush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try it. Actually I want the legend likes the [link](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radlegend/overview).